# Meteor reactive publishes/subscribes

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

I am currently working on a chat app in meteor. When first entering the room you get 25 messages initially. Now as new messages come into the page, that value should go up accordingly.

Now I so far I have a tried a couple different things, all not giving the desired result.

I have tried setting up a session variable on the client side that reactively re-subscribes to a given publish as the message count goes up. The problem with this route is this gives an adverse effect as new messages come in where all of the messages on the page need to reload because of the subscribe.

I have recently tried using the `reactive-publish` package with little luck in that the package has some various adverse effects of it's own.

What might be the best way to tackle this kind of problem? I am hoping there is a solution where I can set up some kind of publish that just streams in messages based on a numerical value that I in the database for each user.

**EDIT**: To add context

I am thinking something along the lines of

```
Meteor.publish 'messages', (roomId) ->
    dl = // Some value that I pull from the database, which gets updated as new messages come into a room

    Messages.find({room: roomId, type: "user_message"}, {sort: {time: -1}, limit: dl, fields: {_id: 1, name: 1, message: 1, room: 1, time: 1, type: 1}})
```

Comment: So when the subscription gets activated you want up to 25 messages in the past, and everything new after that?

Comment: I want the most recent 25 messages in that room, and than any messages that come after.

Answer (score 1):

A huge amount of flexibility in Pub/Sub flexibility is achievable by using the low-level publications API - so much so that I've just written [a blog post](http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-low-level-publications/) about it.  It should make it pretty clear how you update variables when new documents appear in a query set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want each user to have a unique subscription based on the time that they enter the chat room, i.e. `Meteor.subscribe("messages", roomId, new Date)`, that includes up to 25 messages from before they entered the room. Here's one option:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function (roomId, time) {
  var lastRecent = _.last(Messages.find({
    room: roomId, type: "user_message"
  }, {sort: {time: -1}, limit: 25}).fetch());

  var cutoffTime = lastRecent && lastRecent.time || time;

  return Messages.find({
    room: roomId, type: "user_message", time: {$gt: cutoffTime}
  });
});
```

If you want to successively add e.g. 25 old messages at a time whenever a user scrolls to the top of the chat window, consider that you may not actually need to "subscribe" to those older messages. You may be able to set up a method call like `Meteor.call("getNOlderMessages", {roomId: roomId, N: 25, priorTo: oldestShownTime})` to fetch them, insert them into a local collection on the client (e.g. `OlderMessages = new Meteor.Collection(null);`), and then do something like:

```
<template="messages">
  {{#each olderMessages}} {{> message}} {{/each}}
  {{#each messages}} {{> message}} {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Sorting by `time: -1` already handles the time inherently. What I am looking for is more of a publish that updates as the dl variable updates.

Comment: And the reason I want the limit variable to dynamic is that I also have a system set up where if a user scrolls to the top of the chat box, that I add an additional 25 messages to the publish.

Comment: @Donny At first glance this looks right, but you don't need the sort in the last cursor.

Comment: @David right, one doesn't need the sort in the last cursor, and it's useless because one needs to re-sort on the client anyway.

Comment: @SeanCallahan You should pass the time as an explicit parameter to the publish function unless you're okay with someone entering the chatroom being sent the exact same set of messages as someone who entered an hour ago -- Meteor has clients share publication instances when possible (when the arguments to `subscribe` are the same).